# How to know if a List is homogeneous

Tags: scala, collections, type-safety

I want to know if a `List` is homogeneous.

Here is my code :

`def isHomogeneous(ls: List[Any]) = ls.map(_.getClass).toSet.size == 1`

Is there a better way ?

Comment: As a general note, testing with `getClass` could lead to unexpected results. If you put `Map`s in your list, for example, you may find that `isHomogeneous` will return `false` because `Map`s are implemented with specialized subclasses for maps with a few elements (up to 4, IIRC). The actual class below a hierarchy is typically considered an implementation detail (unless a class is `final`, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def allEqual(xs: Traversable[_]) =
  xs.headOption.forall(head => xs.forall(_ == head))

def isHomogeneous(xs: Traversable[_]) =
  allEqual(xs.view.map(_.getClass))
```

- Keeps the `getClass` business separate from the traversal.
- Uses more general type `Traversable` instead of `List`.
- Works for `Nil`.
- Does not traverse the entire collection unless necessary.

Comment: `xs.tail` might not be efficient on some data structures. Shouldn't `xs.forall(_ == head)` be performing better? Besides that, you could also use `forall` instead of the match, meaning: `xs.headOption.forall(head => xs.forall(_ == head))`

Comment: It would have to be *O(n)* on `Array`. (In this case it would be a `WrappedArray`, but I think it's true for that as well.)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
def isHomogeneous(l: List[Any]) = {
  val t = l(0).getClass
  l.forall(_.getClass == t)
}
```

So if all elements have the same type as the first, it returns true

EDIT: To expand a bit on why I think this solution is better:

- It only loops through the list once
- It can exit early(If the second element is of a different class, it can immediately exit instead of trying other elements)
- It does not create intermediate objects
- It does not require a hashCode method to be implemented (Which it may, depending on the implementation of Set)
- It looks, at least to me, clearer

Comment: If you replace ``l(0)`` with ``l.head``, you can also use the more general type ``Traversable`` instead of ``List``